# Multiple package in same node_modules folder

Tags: npm, npm-install

Is there a way to create multiple npm packages that will install in same folder in node_modules?

For example i have package_1 and package_2. When using npm install i want both to be installed in node_modules/main_package so the folder structure will be:

node_modules/main_package/package_1
node_modules/main_package/package_2

The packages will not be dependent on to each other. I can install one or both.

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: If you list package2 as package1's depencies in package.json of package1. you will get the same.

Comment: As i said in the question, they are not dependencies and you can install 1 or both.

Comment: I didn't say they need to be dependent, You can befool npm that they are dependent. You need to tell npm , some point of time that you want one or both :) that is how you tell .

Comment: @keepwalking Did you get an answer to this? I am also stuck in the same situation.